# Can't install Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face NuGet into Xamarin Studio iOS project

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I tried a lot, but I can't install Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face NuGet into Xamarin Studio iOS project.

I got this error:

```
Could not install package 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face 1.2.5.1'. You are         trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

I tried to update all packages, also Xamarin and still same problem. Only this package does not work - other like Newtonsoft.Json, Mircosoft.Net.HTTP and many other was installed correctly. I tried to install first Microsoft.BCL also Microsoft.BCL.Build and it also does not work.

Maybe you have any thoughts what can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a problem with the Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face 1.2.5.1 NuGet package itself. Whilst it has a portable class library (PCL) folder this does not map to a valid PCL profile:

```
portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81+aspnetcore50
```

If the aspnetcore50 part of that folder is removed then it would install into Xamarin.iOS. As it is, NuGet will not allow you to install it.

The only thing left you can do is unzip the NuGet package and try directly using the assembly. NuGet will not allow you to install it.

I believe there are plans to update the NuGet package to fix this, but that has not yet happened.

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your answer. So as I understand it is not that easy to install it into iOS project in Xamarin.
I figured out that I can add it into new PCL project in my solution and than make a reference to it in my iOS project. But I don't want to rewrite whole app into cross-platform code. 
I need that specific native iOS code to show that even if it should be C-obj I can use C# (college project ;>)

So maybe is there any workaround to make it work with my iOS project?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want to do. There is a [json api](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/face-api) so you could avoid using the Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face NuGet package. There also seems to be [an example native iOS project sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-face-ios)